# VueJs: Multiple components on one view with different value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am a beginner in VueJs. I want to show the same component multiple times on one view. So I added this code:

```
<StarRatingReadonly :rating="i" v-for="i in 5" :key="i"></StarRatingReadonly>
```

My StarRating-Script component looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/s3dbfhr9/2/

There should always be 5 stars. And depending on the rating it should contains as many green stars. Example: If rating is three, there has to be three green stars and two grey ones.
But the value is just showed once.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the full template? It doesn't seem to be complete here

Comment: I added the full template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: `radio` inputs are meant to chose **a single value among multiple choices**. It means that within a `fieldset`, only **one** `radio` can be `checked` at the time.

It's clearer if you remove your `.rate > input { display: none; }`, you'll see you have only one radio checked.

#### Solution

Just **use `checkbox` instead of `radio`**. They do the same except that multiple checkboxes can be selected at the same time.

Also, you should update your `:checked=""` conditions so that it's checked if the rating is actually greater than or equal to the input value:

```html
<fieldset class="rate">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    :checked="rating >= 5"
  ><label for="rating10" title="5 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    value="4.5"
    :checked="rating >= 4.5"
  ><label class="half" for="rating9" title="4 1/2 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    value="4"
    :checked="rating >= 4"
  ><label for="rating8" title="4 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    value="3.5"
    :checked="rating >= 3.5"
  ><label class="half" for="rating7" title="3 1/2 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    value="3"
    :checked="rating >= 3"
  ><label for="rating5" title="3 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    value="2.5"
    :checked="rating >= 2.5"
  ><label class="half" for="rating4" title="2 1/2 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    :checked="rating >= 2"
  ><label for="rating3" title="2 stars"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    :checked="rating >= 1.5"
  ><label class="half" for="rating2" title="1 1/2 star"></label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="rating"
    :checked="rating >= 1"
  ><label for="rating1" title="1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Working fork of your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kapcash/vzwpc5br/

---

Note: you could use a `v-for` inside your rating component to render your inputs and simplify the template.

Answer (score 1):

As you added `:checked="ratingValue == 1"`, It will always checked the radio input which verify this condition.

As I don't have your full child template code. Right now it is just showing simple radio inputs.

Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('StarRatingReadonly', {
  props: ['rating'],
  template: `<input
    type="radio"
    id="rating1"
    name="rating"
    :checked="rating === 1"
  >`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <star-rating-readonly v-for="i in 5" :key="i" :rating="i"></star-rating-readonly>
</div>
```

Can you please check above code snippet and complete the remaining code you have. So that I can look into the requirement/issue you are facing.